# PostgreSQL unique constrain not using exact match

Tags: sql, postgresql

When inserting into a PostgreSQL database with an unique constrain on a string and a date, the exact match for the string part is not being used. As per below, when I try to insert the combination of 'AA','2010-01-04' into DB, I get a duplicate violation for A, 2010-01-04 already existing.

```
INSERT INTO orats_opt
(ticker,dates,stockpx,iv30,iv60,iv90,m1atmiv,m1dtex,m2atmiv,m2dtex,m3atmiv,m3dtex,m4atmiv,m4dtex,slope,deriv,slope_inf,deriv_inf,dclsHV10,dclsHV20,dclsHV60,dclsHV120,dclsHV252,dORHV10,dORHV20,dORHV60,dORHV120,dORHV252)
VALUES ( 'AA','2010-01-04
+00'::date,16.63,47.68,43.25,43.16,52.34,12.0,43.28,47.0,43.15,103.0,43.08,194.0,2.28,0.03878,2.323,0.05939,45.21,47.01,45.15,47.52,71.41,41.94,49.32,44.63,47.31,60.38)
```

> ```
> ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_ticker_date"
> DETAIL:  Key (ticker, dates)=(A, 2010-01-04) already exists.
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "unique_ticker_date"
> SQL state: 23505
> Detail: Key (ticker, dates)=(A, 2010-01-04) already exists.
> ```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete `create table` statement for `orats_opt` and the corresponding unique constraint (or index). **[edit]** your question. Do **not** add code or additional information in comments

Comment: table structure please, preferably from psqls `\d+ orats_opt`

Comment: Perhaps `ticker` is defined as `char(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

My immediate guess, based on the behaviour and the lack of other errors, is that your unique constraint is messed up.  For example, if you mistakenly tried to cast the items in the unique constraint and got this wrong, you could be creating the wrong unique keys.  A good example might be if you had in your table definition:

```
unique("char"(ticker), date(dates))
```

Or if you had a trigger which set ticket to `"char"(ticker)` this would cause the same.

However by default unique constraints are named with _key at the end, so this sounds like a custom index.  The following could create this as well:

```
create unique index unique_ticker_date("char"(ticker), date(dates))
```

could have the same effect.

To fix it try:

```
drop index unique_ticker_date;
create unique index unique_ticker_date on orats_opt(ticker, dates);
```